# Domain has already been taken

Tags: heroku, dns

I have an app on Heroku.
I am trying to do the steps from [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) so that my Application has a recognizable domain name.

When I enter the following command (with my own domain) :
`heroku domains:add www.example.com`

I receive this error message :

```
Adding www.example.com to fierce-escarpment-8305... failed<br/>

 !    Domain has already been taken
```

I don't understand what that means. I cancelled my account on my other hosting service so that I could free my domain name and I reseted my infos with my domain provider so that my domain points to a temp page.

Ok ! So I now understand (I think) what I had to change on my domain provider site. I think my infos are now correct, because I don't have the  "!    Domain has already been taken" error message.
Now, I have this message : 
»heroku domains:add www.math-moi.com
 !    No app specified.
 !    Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use with --app 
» heroku domains:add www.math-moi.com --app heroku-fierce-escarpment-8305
Adding www.math-moi.com to heroku-fierce-escarpment-8305... failed
 !    App not found

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

---

»heroku domains:add www.math-moi.com --app heroku-fierce-escarpment-8305.herokuapp.com
Adding www.math-moi.com to heroku-fierce-escarpment-8305.herokuapp.com... failed
 !    Resource not found

---

Still having the error message ...

```
»heroku domains:add www.math-moi.com --app fierce-escarpment-8305<br/>
Adding www.math-moi.com to fierce-escarpment-8305... failed<br/>
 !    Domain has already been taken
```

Comment: Domains can't be "freed", they are transferred from one registrar to another. If you need to point your domain to a new server or host, you edit the DNS records.

Comment: It seems to be different with Heroku from what I had to do the last time. I don't really understand and there is not a lot of explications.

Comment: So... I guess my infos on my domain provider website has been properly updated.
 
»host www.math-moi.com

www.math-moi.com is an alias for fierce-escarpment-8305.herokuapp.com.

fierce-escarpment-8305.herokuapp.com has address 174.129.192.155

But, I still can't add the domain to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the domain that you own. The domain example.com is already claimed by someone else and multiple accounts cannot be assigned to the same domain.

```
 heroku domains:add www.example.com
```

should become:

```
 heroku domains:add www.YOURDOMAINHERE.com
```

Comment: That is what I did. I change it to my own domain. And it did not work.